# Auto-incrementing primary key is making big jumps as if huge numbers of rows are getting deleted and re-inserted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Auto-incrementing primary key is making big jumps as if huge numbers of rows are getting deleted and re-inserted. I'm positive they aren't getting deleted though. Nowhere in my code do I delete from the table!

I have a table with a `bigint` column as auto incrementing primary key and a `varchar` column that is indexed.

I noticed that the primary key values made huge jumps. For example..

```
ID      Name
1       Foo
2       Bar
12586   Woo
12587   Hoo
987698  What
987698  Is Going On
```

The primary key is clustered. Could that be it?

If it keeps making these big jumps, it's going to overflow. What will happen then?

Comment: Do you have a lot of transactions getting rolled back?

Comment: Does Entity Framework use transactions?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "auto incrementing primary key," do you mean `IDENTITY(1,1)`, or something else?

Over what time period are you seeing the increase from 1 to 987698? And why are you seeing that last value twice?

Have you run SQL Profiler to look at the activity on that table?

Are you using transactions? If so, are you experiencing rollbacks or exceptions/errors?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the identity properties of your table. (Ident_current,Ident_seed,Ident_incr). Are you using transactions ?

Comment: The identity specification is - increment: 1 seed: 1

Comment: I guess, your transactions are getting rolledback. if so you will lose the identies. You can use [code](DBCC CHECKIDENT ("TableName");) to rest the identity to the last max value when it is rolling back.

Comment: Whats up? Able to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has changed tradition sequence in SQL 2012.  You can implement custom sequencing.  Just follow this link.  This would help you to solve your problem.

--Create the Test schema
CREATE SCHEMA Test

-- Create a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1

-- Insert three records
INSERT Test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1, 'Tire', 2)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx